# How to disable @PostConstruct in Spring during Test

Tags: java, spring, annotations, postconstruct

Within a Spring Component I have a `@PostConstruct` statement. Similar to below:

```
@Singleton
@Component("filelist")
public class FileListService extends BaseService {

    private List listOfFiles = new Arrays.list();

    //some other functions


    @PostConstruct
    public void populate () {

        for (File f : FileUtils.listFiles(new File(SystemUtils.JAVA_IO_TMPDIR), new String[]{"txt"},true)){
            listOfFiles.add(f.getName());
        }   
    }

    @Override
    public long count() throws DataSourceException {
        return listOfFiles.size();
    }

    //  more methods .....
}
```

During Unit tests I would not like to have the `@PostConstruct` function called, is there a way to telling Spring not to do post processing? Or is there a better Annotation for calling a initiation method on a class durning non-testing ?

Comment: Is it FileListService you want to test or other classes depending on it?

Comment: The FileListService is required by a Web Service which is being tested - public class FileWSTest extends JerseyTest, which is using grizzly web container

Comment: You can either mock it using a subclass or factor out the initialization part. You can place mock in package scanned only for tests and mark it as `@Primary`.

Comment: this (from mrembisz) worked - added the mock classes into the config directly with @Primary tag, and ensure that the injected/autowired were interface. one class override removing function and the other complete class mocked including the loading of database stuff, removed the need for a in-memory datbase during test ... how to give credit ?

Comment: I have reposted it as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you are not testing `FileListService` but a depending class, you can mock it for tests. Make a mock version in a separate test package which is scanned only by test context. Mark it with `@Primary` annotation so it takes precedence over production version.

Answer (score 8):

Any of:

1. Subclass `FileListService` in your test and override the method to do nothing (as mrembisz says, you would need to place the subclass in package scanned only for tests and mark it as `@Primary`)
2. Change `FileListService` so the list of files is injected by Spring (this is a cleaner design anyway), and in your tests, inject an empty list
3. Just create it with `new FileListService()` and inject the dependencies yourself
4. Boot up Spring using a different configuration file/class, without using annotation configuration.

Comment: The FileListService is a @Component which is found by Spring using <context:annotation-config /> <context:component-scan base-package="com.app.ws" />, so overriding wouldn't stop spring from finding it. Also the some PostConstruct will actually do other things, so i would need to inject a function and not data. I'll guess i would need a way of injecting a Mocked class that overrides the exsisting bean-id

Answer (score 5):

Declare a bean to override the existing class and make it Primary.

```
@Bean
@Primary
public FileListService fileListService() {
 return mock(FileListService.class);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check the profile as this:

```
  @PostConstruct
    public void populate () {
       if (!Arrays.asList(this.environment.getActiveProfiles()).contains("test")) {    
         for (File f : FileUtils.listFiles(new File(SystemUtils.JAVA_IO_TMPDIR), new 
              String[]{"txt"},true)){
            listOfFiles.add(f.getName());
          } 

        }           
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to create another bean (Service in this case) having exactly that @PostConstruct method.

In this way you are able to easily mock the new bean preventing the @PostConstruct method from being called.
I've written a simple proof of concept in SpringBoot in order to make it more clear:

**1)** First we **define** our **Service without @PostConstruct** method

```java
@Service
@RefreshScope
public class SomeService {
 
    public void doSomethingAfterPostConstruct() throws Exception  {
        // ...
    }

}
```

**2)** Then we **define another service with** the **@PostConstruct** method we need for the first service

```java
@Service
public class PostConstructService {

    @Autowired
    SomeService someService;

    @PostConstruct
    public void doSomething() throws Exception {
        someService.doSomethingAfterPostConstruct();
    }
}
```

**3)** In the end we can easily **mock the @PostConstruct method by mocking its own class**

```java
/** Test class to extend **/
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public abstract class AbstractTestConfig {

    @MockBean
    PostConstructService postConstructServiceMocked;

}
```

Hope this helps you! :)