# Stop Spring Boot Test from hitting @PostContruct of SpringBootApplication class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I have a SpringBootApplication class that has a `@PostConstruct` method like that (it initializes the type of database connection):

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootApp extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    public static boolean workOffline = false;
    private boolean setupSchema = false;
    private IGraphService graphService;
    private DbC conf;

    @Autowired
    public SpringBootApp(IGraphService graphService, DbC conf)
    {
        this.graphService = graphService;
        this.conf = conf;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootApp.class, args);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void initializeDB() {
        if (workOffline) {
            conf.setupOfflineEnvironment();
            return;
        }
        else {
            conf.setupProdEnvironment();
        }
        if (setupSchema) {
            graphService.setupTestUsers();
        }
    }
}
```

I am also using Spring Boot Tests that `extend` this base class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@Ignore
@SpringBootTest
public class BaseTest {

    @Before
    public void beforeTest() {

        if (SpringBootApp.workOffline) {
            conf.setupOfflineEnvironment();
        } else {
            conf.setupTestEnvironment();
        }

        graphService.setupTestUsers();}
    @After
    public void afterTest() {
        graphService.deleteAllData();
    }
}
```

My tests are under `tests/` while my source code is under `src/`

Unfortunately there are cases that `beforeTest()` will execute before `@PostConstuct` and there are cases that it will execute after.. Is there a way to make my tests run with `@SprinbBootTest` without entering/constructiong the `SpringBootApp` class at all?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using Spring profiles and configuration annotations?  
 
For example you can annotate the `SpringBootApp` class with `@Profile("application")`.  

Then abstract your `@Before` and `@After`  annotations  and methods into a `TestConfig` class which is annotated with `@Configuration` and `@Profile("test").`   

Then finally in your `BaseTest` class (or other test classes) you can annotate it with `@ActiveProfiles("test")` . This should stop your `SpringBootApp` class from being initialised. Does something like this work?

Comment: I would probably manage `workOffline` via a spring property, and then set the property to false using [`SpringBootTest#properties`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/context/SpringBootTest.html#properties--)

Comment: @ninj that is interesting! could you please show an example how to set a variable to a specific value using SprinbBoot ? Thanks

Comment: What my problem is essentially here is to somehow say to @SpringBootApplication that I am actully running tests now and it is not teh actual application.. is there a way to do that?

Comment: This can only work through defining configuration classes. Spring's [blog](https://spring.io/blog/2016/04/15/testing-improvements-in-spring-boot-1-4) and [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html) states for `@SpringBootTest` : "The test will first attempt to load @Configuration from any inner-classes, and if that fails, it will search for your primary @SpringBootApplication class." "The search algorithm works up from the package that contains the test until it finds a @SpringBootApplication or @SpringBootConfiguration annotated class"

Comment: I already solved this problem before.
Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77621938/19749865)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As requested, here's an attempt using spring properties (without an IDE handy, so please forgive any mistakes)

You can set a property for your test using [SpringBootTest#properties](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/context/SpringBootTest.html#properties--)

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@Ignore
@SpringBootTest(properties="springBootApp.workOffline=true")
public class BaseTest {
    @Before
    public void beforeTest() { /* setup */ }

    @After
    public void afterTest() { /* teardown */ }
}
```

Now that we know that we can set the spring property in the test, we can set up the application to use the property:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootApp extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${springBootApp.workOffline:false}")
    private boolean workOffline = false;

    @Value("${springBootApp.setupSchema:false}")
    private boolean setupSchema = false;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initializeDB() {
        if (workOffline) {
            // ...
        } else {
            // ...
        }
        if (setupSchema) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

As I've written this answer I've noticed a couple of things:

- If you're only setting `workOffline` so you can run tests, then you probably just want to move the database setup actions out of the application and into the `BaseTest` class instead.
- Same goes for `setupSchema`
- If you are executing sql for your tests, don't forget about `@Sql` and `@SqlGroup`: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/integration-testing.html#__sql

Anyway, good luck!